# The method request(String...) in the type WebTarget is not applicable for the arguments (MediaType)

Tags: java, jersey

I'm doing Jersey client and getting this error on a line

```
String response = target.path("activities/" + id).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
```

Java - 1.8.0.73 / Jersey - 2.22.2

According to docs - it should work, eclipse shows 3 overloads, but still:
**The method request(String...) in the type WebTarget is not applicable for the arguments (MediaType)**

Why it doesn't see other overloads and throws an exception?

Answer (score 4):

Wrong MediaType was imported - org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.MediaType instead of javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType

Comment: You can and should  accept your own answer. FYI, it helped me. Thanks!